# How do I stop a jQuery hover event from applying css text-shadow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this jQuery event triggering a text-shadow:

```
$(".leftColumn").hover(function (){
  $(".leftColumn h2").css("text-shadow", "0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
},function(){});
```

The problem is that once the text-shadow is applied to the h2, it remains applied even after I stop hovering over leftColumn. How do I make the text shadow go away?

I tried:

```
$(".leftColumn").hover(function (){
  $(".leftColumn h2").css("text-shadow", "0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
},function(){
  $(".leftColumn h2").css("text-shadow", "none");
});
```

But all that did was prevent the text-shadow from being applied at all.

Comment: use CSS rather than javascript - `.leftColumn:hover h2 { text-shadow: ......}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jaromanda X mentioned, that's a case better to be handled in CSS side.

```css
.leftColumn:hover h2 {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0,   0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="leftColumn">
  <h2>I'm H1</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".leftColumn h2").css("text-shadow", "unset");
```

use 'unset' instead of 'none', if you have to use jquery to do this. 
text-shadow doesn't have a 'none' value.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` event. Also define class properties in css and use `addClass` & `removeClass` properties.Using jquery `.css` will add inline style to the element.

Alternatively css `:hover` can also be used

```js
$(".leftColumn").on('mouseover', 'h2', function() {
  $(this).addClass('addShadow');
});
$(".leftColumn").on('mouseout', "h2", function() {
  $(this).removeClass('addShadow');
});
```

```css
.addShadow {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftColumn">
  <h2> Hovering element</h2>

</div>
```